# JNDI lookup in ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed

Tags: java, jndi, jboss7.x, servlet-listeners

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 and servlet-api 2.5.

I have to shutdown some objects which located in JNDI on application shutdown.

I'm using `ServletContextListener` for this purposes:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ((TaskClient) new InitialContext().lookup("myName")).disconnect();
    }
}
```

But I get exception:

```
Error looking up myName, service service 
jboss.naming.context.java.myName is not started
```

If I try to lookup the object when application is running everything is fine.

Thank you for any help.

---

**update**

How I bind data to jndi:

```
public class MyJbpmServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public static final String TASK_CLIENT_JNDI_NAME = "myJbpmTaskClient";
    private Log logger = SLF4JLogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            TaskClient tc = ...
            // long initialization of TaskClient
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            context.bind(TASK_CLIENT_JNDI_NAME, client);
        } catch (NamingException exception) {
            logger.error("Cannot bind task client", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            ((TaskClient) new InitialContext().lookup(TASK_CLIENT_JNDI_NAME)).disconnect();
        } catch (NamingException exception) {
            logger.error("Cannot obtain task client", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

The object is accessible on following path `TASK_CLIENT_JNDI_NAME` when application runs. But when `contextDestroyed` called I have `NamingException`.

I don't know how and when it's destroyed. I only sure that I'm not rebind or unbind it.

---

**update2**

I also tried to use jndi paths `java:comp/myName`, `java:comp/env/myName`, `java:/myName`, `java:jboss/myName`. Behavior is the same: it possible to lookup object when application runs and unable to do it when `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed` method called.

Comment: How do you shutdown the application? Do you stop the JBoss instance?

Comment: @Funtik if I shutdown the JBoss instance and undeploy the application the behavior is the same.

Comment: You've mentioned that you want to shutdown the application. How do you do that? Do you use the JBoss admin console for that? or you just shutdown the entire instance of JBoss?

Comment: @Funtik I shutdown the application in two ways: the first is standart undeploy (using maven plugin, but I think that undeploy which using admin console is the same) and the second is shutdown entire instance of JBoss. Both methods not working in the same way.

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin Maybe it silly, but can you lookup that object from JNDI when application run?

Comment: @user1516873 yes, I can. Everything is fine when application runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a JBoss bug to me, I created [AS7-5746](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5746)